# Delphi cannot connect to Access 2019

Tags: ms-access, delphi

I have a Delphi 10 programme which reads an Access database (.mdb). I believe it does this through DAO. I was using Access 2016 and this worked fine. I have now upgraded to Access 2019 and it crashes (specifically, in the DAO_TLB unit it errors saying, "Project raised exception class EOleSysError with message 'Class not registered'.")

I am not sure what information I should include here that would be useful - please let me know.

Comment: Try the [access database engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb

Comment: That works - thank you. I installed the 2016 Access Engine and that alone fixed the problem, without any change to the programme's code.